# How to implement PhoneGap Android background service

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to implement the example on this page [phonegap-android-background-service](http://red-folder.blogspot.com/2012/09/phonegap-android-background-service.html) but so far having a problem getting it to work.

My error reports;

```
Error: Plugin unable to bind to background service
```

then a javascript alert;

```
ErrorCode: -4, Success: false, RegisteredForUpdates:false,RegisteredForBootStart:false,ErrorMessage: Plugin unable to to bind to background service,ServiceRunning: false
```

Android Device os: 4.2.1 jELLY Bean

Cordova Version: 2.9 RC 1

Answer (score 2):

Follow the Steps 
1) Go to Assets->www Folder->myService-2.7.0 
set package path

cordova.define( 'cordova/plugin/myService', function(require, exports, module) {
                                                CreateBackgroundService('com.yournamespace.yourappname.MyService', require, exports, module);
                                            });

Change ->com.yournamespace.yourappname

this path as your package name.

Answer (score 0):

you need an Android platform at least 4.4.x (kitkat)

Comment: Was able to implement using a PhoneGap plugin.