# 'Plugin unable to bind to background service' - Red-folder phonegap plugin

Tags: java, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I've been trying to create a background service for my cordova app using [this](https://github.com/Red-Folder/bgs-core/wiki/Build-your-own-Background-Service) tutorial. I've been getting an error which says: `Plugin unable to bind to background service.` I've been researching this error and multiple fixes are offered on github [here](https://github.com/Red-Folder/bgs-core/issues/18). However these fixes don't fix my problem. I've posted a comment in the link above explaining the problem, but there is no fix yet. there are more comments saying they encounter the same problem though.

The solution offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22642590/how-to-implement-phonegap-android-background-service), doesn't relate to my problem and neither fixes it.

I've followed the exact instructions of the tutorial and have used the same names as mentioned in the tutorial. My package name is: `com.red_folder.phonegap.plugin.backgroundservice.sample`
And declared the service in the `AndroidManifest.xml` like this:

```
<service android:name="com.red_folder.phonegap.plugin.backgroundservice.sample.MyService">
   <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.red_folder.phonegap.plugin.backgroundservice.sample.MyService" />
   </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Does anyone here have a workaround for this problem?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Found it!!!!:)

Firstly check that you have

package com.red_folder.phonegap.plugin.backgroundservice.BackgroundService;

inside MyService.java on top.

I did not notice that was missing.

After you do that go to file com.red_folder.phonegap.plugin.backgroundservice.BackgroundService.BackgroundServicePluginLogic.java

line 163 and change

String serviceName =  data.getString(0);

to

String serviceName = "com.red_folder.phonegap.plugin.backgroundservice.BackgroundService.MyService";

Otherwise i followed below steps(i did this one first and is working but i think the above could be also a solution, so as not to change files, positions etc..).

1. move MyService.java from com.red_folder.phonegap.plugin.backgroundservice.BackgroundService to com.my.app

2.MyService.java is the following

```
package com.my.app;

import android.util.Log;

import com.red_folder.phonegap.plugin.backgroundservice.BackgroundService;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class MyService extends BackgroundService {
    @Override
    protected JSONObject doWork() {
        JSONObject result = new JSONObject();

        try {
            // Following three lines simply produce a text string with Hello World and the date & time (UK format)
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
            String now = df.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            String msg = "Hello World - its currently " + now;

            // We output the message to the logcat
            Log.d("MyService", msg);

            // We also provide the same message in our JSON Result
            result.put("Message", msg);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // In production code, you would have some exception handling here
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject getConfig() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void setConfig(JSONObject config) {

    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject initialiseLatestResult() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

3. Change also in AndroidManifest.xml

   ```
   <service android:name="com.my.app.MyService">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="com.my.app.MyService" />
       </intent-filter>
   </service>
   ```
4. Go to file com.red_folder.phonegap.plugin.backgroundservice.BackgroundService.BackgroundServicePluginLogic.java

line 163 and change

String serviceName =  data.getString(0);

to

String serviceName = "com.my.app.MyService";

i hope to help you!!!